# How can i get different request body schemas, depending on selected Media type in NestJs/Swagger?

Tags: swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I want to implement something like that:

```
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/FaceEnrollmentRequest'
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/FaceEnrollmentRequestMultipart'
```